# Facebook "Like" stats not showing up in Facebook Insights?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I just noticed one of the pages on my site has 46 likes, but they don't show up at all in Facebook Insights:

http://www.datesphere.com/blog/2011/01/26/the-top-10-dating-site-myths/ugly-klint/

The like button on that page is implemented via the Sociable plugin, but unfortunately both the FB developer and Sociable documentation are completely useless and/or non-existent, so I thought I'd ask you fine people.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `www.datesphere.com` as your Facebook Insights domain? The full domain has to match, so if your domain is set to `datesphere.com`, the page won't show up.

Comment: It will, as www.datesphere.com matches *.datesphere.com

Comment: No it won't. From the documentation (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/): "If your site utilizes subdomains, the root file of each subdomain must be claimed separately." You also need to add the <meta> tag described there, which your site doesn't have.

Comment: sorry, confused it with apps.

Comment: Yes, I added www.datesphere.com to Facebook Insights. Any other ideas?

Comment: Actually, when I go to facbeookcom/insights it just says "datesphere.com". When I try adding www.datesphere.com it just redirects me to the insights page for datesphere.com, so I don't know if I entered it as www before or not, and there doesn't seem to be a way to edit an existing Insights profile. Any ideas?

Comment: I've just found this question because I seem to have exactly the same issue. When I initially manually added the sites to Insights, I most definitely specified the `www.`, but thereafter they're just referred to as `domain.co.uk` in the drop-down menu. Also, with my own Facebook ID added as admin in a `meta` tag as it should do for Insights to work, the `like` box now has a direct link to Insights on it. Even clicking this Insights link on the `like` box itself produces the same Insights page with zero likes - even though the box states over 20 likes.

Answer (score 0):

I had just set up domain insights and had a similar sounding problem. I found this in the FAQ at the bottom of the [Insights doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/), which may mean (for me), just wait a bit.

> **I am a Page administrator. Why am I not able to see Insights for my Page?**
>
> Insights are only available to pages which are liked by at least
> 30 people. Insights will start showing up for your page once your page
> has 30 users who like it.